# Post message from popup to parent of a different domain

Tags: javascript, post, cross-domain

I'm implementing a prototype for handling payments on a website. What I want to do is to open a popup to my site from another domain where the user will do the purchase, and then relay to the parent site that the purchase has been completed.
In the parent I have a simple script that checks for messages:

```
var popup;
let button = document.getElementById("chip_button");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let popup = window.open('http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/?price=10','payment-window','width=600,height=400');
    window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
        console.log(event.data);
      });
 });
```

But I'm struggling to find a way for the popup to relay a message to the parent.  The relevant code for the popup:

```
document.getElementById("buy-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
        fetch("{% url 'process_payment'%}", {
          method: "post",
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "X-CSRFToken": csrf_token
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({'price':price})
          })
          .then( (response) => response.json()) 
          .then(data => {
            window.parent.postMessage(data, "*")
          });
        });
```

The most relevant part of the code is `window.parent.postMessage(data, "*")`. `window.parent` only seems to work for iframes, which I prefer not to use right now due to cookie issues. `window.opener` doesn't work either as the sites are of different domains. Is there any other way to make this work?